# Como utilizar o HTML ou CSS no Android Studio?

Tags: html, css, css3, android-studio

Gostaria de saber como posso estruturar meu app com HTML, e estilizá-lo com CSS também. Eu quero colocar um fieldset para formar uma tabela. Procurei tutoriais na internet mas não entendi bem como utilizar.

Eu quero que o lvDolar, do XML abaixo, esteja contornado por um fieldset:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.teste.application.VerDolar"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        **android:id="@+id/lvDolar"**
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Essa é minha classe java:

```
package teste;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.rainah.application.R;

import java.util.List;


public class VerDolar extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView lvDolar;
    private List<Dolar> dolar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_dolar);
        setTitle("Dolar");

        lvDolar = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDolar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        List<Dolar> listDolar = db.selectDolar();

        ArrayAdapter<Dolar> list = new ArrayAdapter<Dolar>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listDolar);

        lvDolar.setAdapter(list);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_ver_dolar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        //int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                break;
            case R.id.action_new:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddDolar.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

Agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar, porque creio ser uma dúvida relativamente simples, porém estou quebrando a cabeça para entender como funciona isso no android studio. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: O Android Studio é focado em aplicação Android, não sei se vai conseguir  fazer isso com essa IDE. O que pessoal faz, é desenvolver uma página web resposiva, e criar um aplicativo que faz acesso a essa página.

Answer (score 2):

Para utilizar CSS em um aplicação Android, você deve ter toda sua aplicação dentro de uma WebView, ou seja, não se pode fazer com que os componentes definidos no XML de uma Activity peguem o estilo de um CSS.

O estilo aplicado a uma Activity (ou elementos dela) deve ser programado no próprio XML da Activity ou em um xml separado (geralmente o styles.xml).

Para usar de fato o CSS, reescreva sua aplicação em uma "aplicação" HTML e no Android utilize uma WebView para exibir os HTMLs da sua aplicação. (veja o 3o link das referências). Para criar "aplicações" HTML, pode-se utilizar o PhongeGap ou Ionic, que tem um bom suporte de comunidade e para programar exigem conhecimento de HTML, CSS e Javascript (Angular).

Finalizando: Para resolver seu problema de fato, que é colocar um **fieldset** em volta do campo, há algumas alternativas:
- adicionar uma TextView atrás do componente, sem texto, um pouco maior que o componente para simular a borda;
- adicionar um "shape" em volta do componente;
- adicionar um Bitmap atrás do componente.

Referências:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview

http://android-pro.blogspot.com.br/2010/08/using-themes-and-styles-in-android.html

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bd6c67/use-html-and-css-file-in-android-apps/

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

http://www.devmedia.com.br/android-layouts-aprendendo-tecnicas-de-layout-no-android/30790

Answer (score -1):

O android studio é focado no desenvolvimento de aplicações nativas, para utilizar HTML e CSS sugiro a utilização do CORDOVA, para o desenvolvimento de aplicativos híbridos, uma sugestão também ao invés de desenvolver o layout responsivo, o que da um certo trabalho, tente utilizar um framework de mercado sugiro IONIC

Link:

https://cordova.apache.org/

https://ionicframework.com/